# How to make iPhoneHTTPServer secure server

Tags: iphone, security, http, https

I am very new to iPhone development.

I downloaded the iPhoneHTTPServer application from bellow link.
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/tree/master/Samples/iPhoneHTTPServer

It works fine for HTTP request.

Now I want to make it as a secure server. (use HTTPS)
for that I have override following two methods in MyHTTPConnection.m

I am sure about changes in this method:

```
 /**
 * Overrides HTTPConnection's method
 **/
 - (BOOL)isSecureServer
 {
    // Create an HTTPS server (all connections will be secured via SSL/TLS)
    return YES; 
 }
```

I need to apply changes in bellow method: (Please guide me here.)
PROBLEM : DDKeychain and Cocoa.h is not available for iOS.

```
 /**
  * Overrides HTTPConnection's method
  * 
  * This method is expected to returns an array appropriate for use in  
  * kCFStreamSSLCertificates SSL Settings.
  * It should be an array of SecCertificateRefs except for the first element in
  * the array, which is a SecIdentityRef.
  **/
  - (NSArray *)sslIdentityAndCertificates
  {
      NSArray *result = [DDKeychain SSLIdentityAndCertificates];
      if([result count] == 0)
      {
        [DDKeychain createNewIdentity];
        return [DDKeychain SSLIdentityAndCertificates];
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: Could this be a case of re-implementing the DDKeychain functionality in that code with the iOS equivalent? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved issue with following steps:

1. Export certificate from your **Keychain Access(Mac OS X)**

   - Open Keychain Access
   - Select Certificate, Right click and select Export...
   - Export Certificate with file format : Personal Information Exchange (.p12)
   - Provide name and password to export file.
     FileName: **TestCertificate.p12**
     Password: **test123**   (* try your admin login pass if not worked)
2. Import **TestCertificate.p12** in you XCode project.
3. Add **Security.framework** in your project.
4. Import **Security.h** file in you code.

   `#import <Security/Security.h>`
5. Override and change **sslIdentityAndCertificates** method as bellow.

```
    /**
     * Overrides HTTPConnection's method
     * 
     * This method is expected to returns an array appropriate for use in kCFStreamSSLCertificates SSL Settings.
     * It should be an array of SecCertificateRefs except for the first element in the array, which is a SecIdentityRef.
     **/
    - (NSArray *)sslIdentityAndCertificates
    {    
        SecIdentityRef identityRef = NULL;
        SecCertificateRef certificateRef = NULL;
        SecTrustRef trustRef = NULL;

        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestCertificate" ofType:@"p12"];
        NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath]; 
        CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (CFDataRef)PKCS12Data; 
        CFStringRef password = CFSTR("test123"); 
        const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase }; 
        const void *values[] = { password }; 
        CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL); 
        CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL); 

        OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;   
        securityError =  SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, optionsDictionary, &items); 
        if (securityError == 0) { 
            CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);
            const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
            tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
            identityRef = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
            const void *tempTrust = NULL;
            tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
            trustRef = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed with error code %d",(int)securityError);
            return nil;
        }

        SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef, &certificateRef);
        NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)identityRef, (id)certificateRef, nil];

        return result;    
    }
```

Comment: The server is running but it throws the error Your connection is not private when I load from browser